# repeated array values on click event javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm making a calendar table I'm storing time values in an array time before clicking save this is array values

```
["11am", "11:15am", "11:30am", "11:45am"]
```

after clicking save button if I select other times old times still exist in the array even thought I'm emptying the array before adding new values

```
var time = [];

$( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('taken')) 
    {
        $('.ui-selecting').removeClass('ui-selecting');
        $('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
    }

    time.push($(this).attr('data-time'));
});
```

if I do console.log of the time array before save event I get

```
["11am", "11:15am", "11:30am", "11:45am"]
```

inside save event this is time array

```
["4pm"]
["11:45am", "12am", "12:15am", "12:30am", "12:45am"]
["11:45am", "12am"]
```

this is the save event

```
$('body').on('click', '#save-pop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(time);

    for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) 
    {
        $('[data-day="'+date+'"] div[data-time="'+time[i]+'"]').addClass('taken');
        $('.popup-data').remove();
        $('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
    }
});
```

this is an example of the problem 
https://jsfiddle.net/zuvpr45r/

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking and what the problem is. Can you explain a little more about what is and is not working for you. A working example of the problem would help a lot too.

Comment: What is `this` at `$( ".ui-selected", this )` ?

Comment: it's jquery ui selectable

Comment: i'll make an example to show the problem